# Rabin fairness model confusion

Tags: game-theory

I'm wondering how the Rabin kindness function for player 1 is composed in [1]. Specifically: How is the equitable payoff calculated with [1]? The correct equitable payoff should be 6X if f1(Trust, Share) and 8.5X if f1(Trust, Grab).

Equitable payoff definition: Player 2's highest payoff in PI(bj) and the lowest payoff of player j among points that are pareto-efficient in PI(bj).

I think there are only 2 really pareto-efficient payoffs: Trust/Share and Trust/Grab. 
To calculate the equitable payoff I would then use (6X+6X)/2 for Share and (12X+12X)/2 for Grab (as there are for both cases each only 1 pareto-efficient outcomes). Perhaps the term pareto efficient is not strictly meant here (because it doesn't lay on the production possibility frontier) and also includes 5X;5X on Grab because Player 2 cannot be better off without taking something from Player 1 away.

Payoff table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIzu7.png

Comment: What does [1] refer to in the OP?

Comment: That's just the payoff table. I couldn't post any proper links and then had to paste a simple link. I forgot to adjust the [1] then, sorry.